# Recursive binary tree class of Fibonacci sequence and reverse

Tags: java

```
public class MyFibonacci {

    public static void main(String a[]){

         int febCount = 15;
         int[] feb = new int[febCount];
         feb[0] = 0;
         feb[1] = 1;
         for(int i=2; i < febCount; i++){
             feb[i] = feb[i-1] + feb[i-2];
         }

         for(int i=0; i< febCount; i++){
                 System.out.print(feb[i] + " ");
         }
    }
}
```

What do I need to add in this so I can reverse the printed fiboonaci series?

Comment: what do you mean by "reverse"?

Comment: if its urgent because your homework is due, then I urge you to start coding them. we'll provide help on specific questions

Comment: Can't you just loop from the end to the start of the array when printing the numbers?

Answer (score 0):

This is the sequence you get

```
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377
```

To revert it, you can start from the last two numbers (377 and 233) and then calculating the next ones *subtracting* instead of *adding*:

```
377, 233, (377-233), ...
377, 233, 144, (233-144), ...
```

something like this

```
Main() {
    int febCount = 15;
    int[] feb = new int[febCount];
    feb[0] = 0;
    feb[1] = 1;
    for(int i=2; i < febCount; i++){
        feb[i] = feb[i-1] + feb[i-2];
    }

    for(int i=0; i< febCount; i++){
            System.out.print(feb[i] + " ");
    }

    System.out.println();
    feb[0] = feb[14];
    feb[1] = feb[13];
    for(int i=2; i < febCount; i++){
        feb[i] = feb[i-2] - feb[i-1];
    }

    for(int i=0; i< febCount; i++){
            System.out.print(feb[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you could just loop through the array backwards when printing, which would be simpler.

Comment: Or you could just print("377 233 144 89 55 34 21 13 8 5 3 2 1 1 0"); but it's pretty obvious that's not the solution he's looking for

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can traverse the array backwards

```
for(int i = febCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    System.out.print(feb[i]);
    if (i > 0) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
}
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just loop through the array backwards when printing the integers.

```
for(int i = febCount - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    System.out.print(feb[i] + " ");
}
```